# Castle Windsor - Register compoents before my Facilities load. - Delay loading configuration file?

Tags: configuration, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, components

I would like to register some components in my Windsor container before my Facilities load - (so that I can use some the components in the facilities)

I was thinking there should be some way to initialize windsor without a configuration file, register some components, and only then load the configuration? - this would result in that my configured facilities would load only after I registered my components.

For example:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

//Register a custom component, which will be used in some of the facilities
container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyService>());

//Now load via the configuration - unfortunately the method "Configure" doesn't exist
container.Configure(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));
```

Appreciate any help on this,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
container.Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```

See [the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx).